# What is the output of '%b' verb when it is floating number

Tags: go, math, floating-point, scientific-notation

According to the go doc, `%b` used with floating number means:

> decimalless scientific notation with exponent a power of two,
> in the manner of strconv.FormatFloat with the 'b' format,
> e.g. -123456p-78

As the code shows below, the program output is

> 8444249301319680p-51

I'm a little confused about `%b` in floating number, can anybody tell me how this result is calculated? Also what does `p-` mean?

```
f := 3.75
fmt.Printf("%b\n", f)
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(f, 'b', -1, 64))
```

Answer (score 4):

The `decimalless scientific notation with exponent a power of two` that means follows:

```
8444249301319680*(2^-51) = 3.75 or 8444249301319680/(2^51) = 3.75
```

`p-51` means `2^-51` which can also be calculated as `1/(2^51)`

Nice article on Floating-Point Arithmetic.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1):

#### The five rules of scientific notation are given below:

1. The base is always 10
2. The exponent must be a non-zero integer, which means it can be either positive or negative
3. The absolute value of the coefficient is greater than or equal to 1 but it should be less than 10
4. The coefficient carries the sign (+) or (-)
5. he mantissa carries the rest of the significant digits

#### `p`

- `%b` scientific notation with exponent a power of two (its `p`)
- `%e` scientific notation

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you also tell me what's  8444249301319680p-51?

Comment: Nick just did it.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth pointing out that the `%b` output is particularly *easy* for the runtime system to generate as well, due to the internal storage format for floating point numbers.

If we ignore "denormalized" floating point numbers (we can add them back later), a floating point number is stored, internally, as 1.bbbbbb...bbb x 2<sup>exp</sup> for some set of bits ("b" here), e.g., the value four is stored as `1.000...000 <exp> 2`.  The value six is stored as `1.100...000 <exp> 2`, the value seven is stored as `1.110...000 <exp> 2`, and eight is stored as `1.000...000 <exp> 3`.  The value seven-and-a-half is `1.111 <exp> 2`, seven and three quarters is `1.1111 <exp> 2`, and so on.  Each bit here, in the 1.bbbb, represents the next power of two lower than the exponent.

To print out `1.111 <exp> 2` with the `%b` format, we simply note that we need four `1` bits in a row, i.e., the value 15 decimal or 0xf or `1111` binary, which causes the exponent to need to be decreased by 3, so that instead of multiplying by 2<sup>2</sup> or 4, we want to multiply by 2<sup>-1</sup> or ½.  So we can take the actual exponent (2), subtract 3 (because we moved the "point" three times to print `1111` binary or 15), and hence print out the string `15p-1`.

That's not what Go's `%b` prints though: it prints `8444249301319680p-50`.  This is the *same value* (so either one would be correct output)—but why?

Well, `8444249301319680` is, in hexadecimal, `1E000000000000`.  Expanded into full binary, this is `1 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.  That's 53 binary digits.  Why 53 binary digits, when four would suffice?

The answer to *that* is found in the link in [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68769439/1256452): IEEE 754 floating point format uses a 53-digit "mantissa" or "significand" (the latter is the better term and the one I usually try to use, but you'll see the former pop up very often).  That is, the `1.bbb...bbb` has 52 `b`s, plus that forced-in leading `1`.  So there are always *exactly* 53 binary digits (for IEEE "double precision").

If we just treat this 53-binary-digit number as a *decimal* number, we can always print it out without a decimal point.  That means we just adjust the power-of-two exponent.

In IEEE754 format, the exponent itself is already stored in "excess form", with 1023 added (for double precision again).  That means that `1.111000...000 <exp> 2` is actually stored with an exponent value of 2+1023 = 1025.  What this means is that to get the actual power of two, the machine code formatting the number is already going to have to subtract 1023.  We can just have it subtract 52 more at the same time.

Last, because the implied `1` is always there, the internal IEEE754 number doesn't actually *store* the `1` bit.  So to read out the value and convert it, the code internally does:

```
decimalPart := machineDependentReinterpretation1(&doubleprec_value)
expPart := machineDependentReinterpretation2(&doubleprec_value)
```

where the machine-dependent-reinterpretation simply extracts the correct bits, puts in the implied `1` bit as needed in the decimal part, subtracts the offset (1023+52) for the exponent part, and then does:

```
fmt.Sprint("%dp%d", decimalPart, expPart)
```

When printing a floating-point number in *decimal*, the base conversion (from base 2 to base 10) is problematic, requiring a lot of code to get the rounding right.  Printing it in binary like this is much easier.

Exercises for the reader, to help with understanding this:

1. Compute 1.10<sub>2</sub> x 2<sup>2</sup>.  Note: 1.1<sub>2</sub> is 1½ decimal.
2. Compute 11.0<sub>2</sub> x 2<sup>1</sup>.  (11.0<sub>2</sub> is 3.)
3. Based on the above, what happens as you "slide the binary point" left and right?
4. (more difficult) Why can we assume a leading 1?  If necessary, read on.

#### Why we can assume a leading 1?

Let's first note that when we use scientific notation in *decimal*, we can't assume a leading `1`.  A number might be 1.7 x 10<sup>3</sup>, or 5.1 x 10<sup>5</sup>, or whatever.  But when we use scientific notation "correctly", the first digit is never *zero*.  That is, we do not write 0.3 x 10<sup>0</sup> but rather 3.0 x 10<sup>-1</sup>.  In this kind of notation, the *number of digits* tells us about the precision, and the *first* digit never has to be zero and generally isn't *supposed* to be zero.  If the first digit were zero, we just move the decimal point and adjust the exponent (see exercises 1 and 2 above).

The same rules apply with floating-point numbers.  Instead of storing `0.01`, for instance, we just slide the binary point two over two positions and get `1.00`, and decrease the exponent by 2.  If we might want to have stored `11.1`, we slide the binary point one position the other way and *increase* the exponent.  Whenever we do this, the *first digit always winds up being a one*.

There is one big exception here, which is: when we do this, we can't store zero!  So we don't do this for the number `0.0`.  In IEEE754, we store `0.0` as all-zero-bits (except for the sign, which we can set to store `-0.0`).  This has an all-zero exponent, which the computer hardware handles as a special case.

#### Denormalized numbers: when we can't assume a leading 1

This system has one notable flaw (which isn't *entirely* fixed by denorms, but nonetheless, IEEE has denorms).  That is: the smallest number we can store "abruptly underflows" to zero.  [Kahan has a 15 page "brief tutorial" on gradual underflow](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/ARITH_17U.pdf), which I am not going to attempt to summarize, but when we hit the minimum allowed exponent (2<sup>-1023</sup>) and want to "get smaller", IEEE lets us stop using these "normalized" numbers with the leading `1` bit.

This doesn't affect the way that Go itself formats floating point numbers, because Go just takes the entire significand "as is".  All we have to do is stop inserting the 2<sup>53</sup> "implied 1" when the input value is a denormalized number, and everything else Just Works.  We can hide this magic inside the machine-dependent `float64` reinterpretation code, or do it explicitly in Go, whichever is more convenient.